# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object в моей реализации хеш-таблицы при попытке создания новых массивов!

Tags: c#, алгоритм, словарь

Возникла проблема конкретно в строках кода обозначенных дефисами или, если еще конкретнее, в строке под крестиками. При обращении к полю 'values' под индексом 'i' почему-то возвращает null. Очень интересно: в какой момент в поле 'values' переопределяется массив так, что в нем все значения становятся равны null, если я даже явно ничего не переопределял.

Также вкратце объясню что происходит: я связал 7 значений с 7 ключами, и затем хеш-функция увидела, что коэффициент заполненности словаря равен 7/10 и начала расширять этот словарь т.е переопределять в полях values и keys массивы с удвоенной величиной и переписывать в них данные из прошлых экземпляров этих массивов. Но когда функция начала переписывать значения ключей в буферный массив для оных, она заметила что из первой имплементации словааря(которую я вообще никак не переопределял)возвращаются значения null т.е я будто перед этим явно переопределил массив строк и не указал в нем никаких значений.

```
class Dict
{
    private int dict_size; 
    public int values_counter = 0;
    private int total = 0; 
    private char[] litters = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    private int[] operands = { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
    private string[] keys; 
    private string[] values; 

    public Dict(int dict_size)
    {
        this.dict_size = dict_size;
        this.keys = new string[this.dict_size];
        this.values = new string[this.dict_size];
    }

    public void Hash(string value, string key)
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.litters.Length; j++)
            {
                if (this.litters[j] == Char.ToUpper(value[i]))
                {
                    this.total += this.operands[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        this.keys[this.total%10] = key;
        this.values[this.values_counter] = value;
        this.values_counter++;          
        this.total = 0;

        if ( ((float) this.values_counter/this.dict_size) >= 0.7f ) //-Проверка коэфф.заполненности--
        { //-----------------------------------------------------
            string[] bufferKeys = new string[this.dict_size];  
            string[] bufferValues = new string[this.dict_size];         

            this.dict_size *= 2; // удвоение величины массивов ключей и значений

            for (int i = 0; i < this.values.Length; i++) // берем строку из поля values
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.values[i].Length; j++) //ххххххххххххххххххххххххххххх
                { //^^^затем обращаемся к каждому отдельному символу в строке^^^
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.litters.Length; k++)//----------------------------------
                    {
                        if (this.litters[k] == Char.ToUpper(this.values[i][j]))
                        {
                            this.total += this.operands[k];
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                bufferKeys[this.total%10] = this.keys[this.total%10];
                total = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.values.Length; i++)
            {
                bufferValues[i] = this.values[i];
            }

            this.keys = new string[this.dict_size];              
            this.values = new string[this.dict_size];

            for (int i = 0; i < bufferValues.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bufferValues[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.litters.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (this.litters[k] == Char.ToUpper(bufferValues[i][j]))
                        {
                            this.total += this.operands[k];
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                this.keys[this.total%10] = bufferKeys[this.total%10];
                total = 0;

            }

            for (int i =0; i < bufferValues.Length; i++)
            {
                this.values[i] = bufferValues[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public string Get(string value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.litters.Length; j++)
            {
                if (this.litters[j] == Char.ToUpper(value[i]))
                {
                    this.total += this.operands[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }           
        var key = this.keys[this.total%10];
        this.total = 0;
        return key;         
    }

    public string[] Keys
    {
        get{return this.keys;}          
    }

    public string[] Values
    {
        get{return this.values;}
    }
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dict dict = new Dict(10);

        dict.Hash("lesha", "kuvaev");            // 1
        dict.Hash("masha", "stepanovna"); // 2
        dict.Hash("macyanya", "chervyakova"); // 3
        dict.Hash("evsikakiya", "spiridonovna"); // 4
        dict.Hash("agent", "cry"); // 5
        dict.Hash("pasha", "kyznecov"); // 6
        dict.Hash("Alex", "Mercer"); // 7
        //dict.Hash("Misha", "repin"); // 8

        /*Console.WriteLine(dict.Get("Alex"));*/

        for (int i = 0; i < dict.Keys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dict.Keys[i] == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-null-");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dict.Keys[i]);
        }

        for (int i =0; i < dict.Values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dict.Values[i] == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-null-");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(dict.Values[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dict.values_counter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все работает корректно, ну в смысле поведение ожидаемое, вы добавляете 7 значений и при этом у вас в это условие не было заходов. На восьмое значение if срабатывает и вы попадаете в цикл. Значения с 0 по 6 позицию в массиве есть (см. картинку), а вот на 7 позиции и далее честные null.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я бы этот цикл обернул в if c проверкой что this.values[i] != null

Comment: Хочу вас поправить что именно на седьмое значение хеш-функция видит, что коэффициент заполенности равен 0.7 и начинает расширение!)
А так - и правда в массиве строк values не все же элементы имеют значение. Как-то сам до этого не мог догадаться пока бомбил.

Comment: @Michail да, вы правы.